# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView

Tags: android, android-dialog

In Adpater not open dialogbox how to give reference of activity

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mcontext, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a Activity context to Dialog's constructor, to do that, you can either

1. Pass your activity as parameter of your Adapter's constructor.
2. Use `itemView.getContext()`, if you are invoking Dialog inside a ViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the activity to the adapter and use a Context variable to save the activity's context and then use this context to create the Dialog instance.